# Can not find symbol method checkSelfPermissions

Tags: android

Build fails with error : `unable to find symbol method checkSelfPermission` 
although I have added the support libraries.
It gives error after building but in Android Studio its not underlined by red color, or marked as missing, still after build, this method missing error is received.

**GRADLE**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(
            : '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':AndroidLicensingLibary')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.+'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

**Main Activity (inside on create after setContent)**

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                        1003);
        }
```

**MESSAGE**

```
/Users/TechwinLabsAndroid/Documents/Gurvinder      Bawa/Projects/redd/src/com/easymitigationinsppro/LoaderActivity.java
Error:(49, 20) error: cannot find symbol method  checkSelfPermission(LoaderActivity,String)
Error:(53, 19) error: cannot find symbol method    requestPermissions(LoaderActivity,String[],int)
/Users/TechwinLabsAndroid/Documents/Gurvinder   Bawa/Projects/redd/src/com/easymitigationinsppro/wizard/fragment/PhotoFra  gment.java
Error:(294, 19) error: cannot find symbol method     requestPermissions(FragmentActivity,String[],int)
Error:(304, 8) error: cannot find symbol method   onRequestPermissionsResult(int,String[],int[])
Error:Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 5.712 secs
```

Comment: Make sure your `compileSdkVersion` is 23 or higher.

Comment: please post your full gradle, dependencies mean nothing

Comment: @CommonsWare compileSdkVersion is 23.

Comment: @tyczj - added.